# How to translate from mips assembly code to C

Tags: c, assembly, mips, reverse-engineering

So I was given the assembly code you see and I did translate it almost correctly but one thing is wrong according to the solutions I provided down here. In the inner for-loop you can see that they increment j by one everytime even tho it is not what the assembly code is saying. According to this line`bne $t6,$t2,e3`, if and only if we branch will we increment j by one otherwise no but if we use for-loop, it will increment it regardless so I used "while loop" because we are only supposed to increment j when `(next/ j) * j != next)`.

**Edit**: Translate the MIPS assembly code of foo2 into C code. The C code should be clear, and use the right types and number of parameters.
We also assume that the program is executed without delay slots.

**Assembly code**

```
.global foo2
foo2: addi $t0,$zero,0
addi $t2,$zero,2

l1: slt $t6,$t0,$a1
beq $t6,$zero,e1
addi $t1,$zero,2

l2: slt $t6,$t1,$t2
beq $t6,$zero,e2
div $t2,$t1
mflo $t6
mul $t6,$t6,$t1
bne $t6,$t2,e3
addi $t1,$zero,2
addi $t2,$t2,1
j l2

e3: addi $t1,$t1,1
j l2

e2: sll $t6,$t0,2
add $t6,$t6,$a0
sw $t2,0($t6)
addi $t0,$t0,1
addi $t2,$t2,1
j l1

e1: sll $t6,$t0,2
add $t6,$t6,$a0
addi $t0,$zero,0
sw $t0,0($t6)
jr $ra
```

C code:

```
void foo2(int* lst, int n) {
    int i, j;
    int next = 2;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 2; j < next; j++) {
            if ((next / j) * j == next) {
                j = 2;
                next++;
            }
        }
        lst[i] = next;
        next++;
    }
    lst[i] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't "translate" code. Take the algorithm and implement it fresh in the target language instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude presumably it's a reverse engineering school assignment.

Comment: @First_1st What is your actual assignment or exercise? Please [edit] your question to tell us. Preferably copy-paste it (as text) in full and complete, so we can see all requirements and limitations.

Comment: The question says "I was given the assembly code you see". Not the algorithm that it implements.

Comment: Which registers do you think correspond to each C variable?

Comment: I'm wary of this code. When I research the `mflo` instruction, it says you mustn't use a `mul` or `div` within 2 instructions after it.

Comment: @Barmar Are you talking about "delay slots", if that is the case we can't use mul or div, then I am to assume that the program is executed without delay slots. I have mentioned it in my edits.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I've now edited my question, sadly this question is about translating a mips code to c.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your assessment that the C code differs in implementation from the assembly code.

The C code uses an if-then statement within an inner for-loop, whereas the assembly code use an if-then-else statement within an inner while-loop.

Whether this difference runs the same or not — has the same ultimate effect on the data structure — is a different assessment.  For example, any sorting algorithm should be able to sort but that doesn't mean they are all equivalent in their internal implementation.  (And certainly a buggy sort is not the same as a correct one..)

Comment: The effect of this difference is that it skips the `j++` when it repeats the iteration after a successful `if`. This seems like a significant difference in the result.

Comment: The `if` condition is effectively the same as `if (next % j == 0)`. I think this is a prime-finding function.